# Security without Login

Tags: authentication, web-application, authorization, payment-gateway

I am working on a web-app where user can access his purchased item using two word/Number combination and then user add card details on same page for the payment of those item.

**Point to be noted**

> 1. I keep the item record on basis of those 2 Word/Number.
> 2. Payment details are verified from third party if details are correct then i 
>      receive a token, I am storing this token as well, for the future payments and 
>      current payments.

Now the problem is, User can view the paid item and new pending item to be paid 
(after initial payments) and he needs to pay for these pending item.
As we already have his payment detail's token i can provide a button **`"Pay Now"`** for the payment of pending item.

He will also have option to update his payment details.

So i wanted to know what are possible threats to my application if a attacker is successful in finding out combination of 2 word that are used for accessing item for a particular user.

Comment: It sounds like you already know what your threats are: someone finding, guessing, or bruteforcing the URL. Only you can know what the impact of that is.

Comment: It's kind of amazon wish list that is public only catch is there is a payment method saved.

Answer (score 2):

> So i wanted to know what are possible threats to my application if a
>   attacker is successful in finding out combination of 2 word that are
>   used for accessing item for a particular user.

Umm..isn't that obvious whatever another user can do with his 2 word combination,an attacker could do the same if he guessed the combination.If you are protecting something this might not be the way and you should have proper session controls.

Comment: Point is even if a attacker finds out those two word combination before actual users use the site all he can do is pay for the those item that he isn't going to do. Problem is in second phase where user has already saved his card and that card is used for future payments. Even if attacker find such account who's card is already saved all he can do is pay for users items or update the card

Comment: The only thing i am concerned about attacker can update the card details with a fake one.